# What do the square brackets mean here?

Tags: ruby

I saw a line in a Rails app like this:

```
Order::PAYMENT_TYPES.map {|p| [t('.payment_type.'+p), p]}
```

`PAYMENT_TYPE` is a string array, and the letter `t` is used for i18n in Rails.

I'm not sure how the square brackets are used here. Apparently they are not for arrays or methods. And I will rewrite this to just `{|p| t('.payment_type.'+p) }`.

So what's the Ruby grammar in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby returns the last statement from a method or a block.  In this case, with the brackets, the block returns an array of two items, so calling that block in `map`, if `PAYMENT_TYPES` had three items, would result in something like `[ [a1, b1], [a2, b2], [a3, b3] ]`.

Answer (score 2):

> Apparently they are not for arrays or methods

Well, it **is** an array literal

```
[t('.payment_type.'+p), p]
# ^ first element       ^ second
```

> I will rewrite this to just ...

If this will work for you, go ahead. We don't know your app's specifics.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that square brackets are not just used for arrays, you can also call Procs.

```
proc = lambda { |name| "Hello, #{name}" }
proc.call('Bob')
=> "Hello, Bob"

proc = lambda { |name| "Hello, #{name}" }
proc['Bob']
=> "Hello, Bob"
```

But in this case, as others have indicated, a new array is being returned resulting in a nested array of arrays.